# C / C++ bootable program which reads file contents from a directory on the computer

Tags: c++, c, linux, bios

I want to create a program which can be stored on a CD or a flash drive.
This program should be able to read a file's content in a directory if exist. For example, search the file "test" in the Linux Desktop Folder which contains "123".

But how do I create such programs which can be directly started from the BIOS? When I create a simple hello-world executable on linux it won't be able to run on a non-linux-OS.

And will libraries such as stdio.h and stdlib.h even still be usable?

Comment: What you are asking here is "how do I write my own OS?", to which the answer is probably several _books_ long.

Comment: Unless, of course, there is some pre-existing method for packaging an app in some low-profile linux distro...

Comment: @ranmat11: why would he write an OS when he can use an existing one? You just have to execute the script after linux boot.

Comment: Yes, but it seems ridiculous to use a several hundred MB OS to run a program probably a few KB in size...

Comment: @Davlog may I ask why you need to do this? There may be a simpler solution.

Comment: You can build tiny Linux micro-distribution with tool like Buildroot and have it run your program at boot.

Comment: @ranmat11: damn small linux is 50mb. And it's not just "running a small program." The bootstrapper will need to provide a file system (as well as the api's to access it), and program execution environment.

Comment: Ah, forgot about DSL, and totally see what you're saying. What I mean is I am wondering why the normal OS cannot be used.

Comment: You guys are thinking way too highlevel. Just build your own custom RISC chip that only executes the code you want, then have it fabbed on a fPGA, and wire it up onto a breadboard. Burn the file onto EEPROM, and BLAM, you got your solution. Software is for babies.

Comment: Did you consider making a GRUB2 module? (GRUB loader knows about many file systems)

Answer (score 4):

Use an existing linux distribution, plenty of them are bootable from a CD/flash drive, with instructions of how to create a new image.

Simply add your program to the boot sequence.

You have to figure out which drive to mount/search though - you're talking about a "directory" not mentioning on what device...

Comment: How is his program now bootable from the BIOS?

Comment: @NikosC.: The linux distribution is bootable from the BIOS, and runs his program on launch, effectively launching his program from the BIOS.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'm not the best expert at this, but i've done some similar stuff and from my knowledge your best shot is putting an assembly program in the boot sector of the data medium (flash, CD-ROM) and then do the work - this is for example how partition software works. When booting from your medium BIOS would start executing the code at boot sector and that is the point where you can kick in. But since it seems that your require support for different file systems this could be very hard to do in assembly. I've worked with FAT32 in assembly but not sure about Linux file systems. Maybe someone has put some assembly code for that online.

Comment: This is a wonderful example of a mostly factually correct yet almost useless answer. You're quite right, but think about who are you answering to, and how likely are they to benefit from such an answer. Besides, writing filesystem access code in assembly is at best misguided advice. I'd consider it the ravings of the lunatic in this day and age, but that's just me :)

Comment: Thanks for the opinion, well, as I mentioned - since i am not facing such issues on a daily basis theses were just my two cents (and that is only prooved by the answer about using a bootable Linux distribution which is much easier to do), and I also mentioned that doing filesystem access from assembly is an overhead, but at least the author is informed about the possibility of having an MBR code, isn't that the point of this site to show all perspectives?;)

Answer (score 1):

The only practical solution that doesn't take in an entire existing operating system kernel like linux is to re-use [grub](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/index.html). Grub is a 32-bit protected mode executable and comes with support for some filesystems. I'd think it has enough of a filesystem implementation to let you iterate through a directory and through the blocks of a file. I very much doubt it will let you do it through the C library API, you'll need to use grub's own internal APIs. And it'll be very much bootable from BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that this is not possible unless you want to write your own mini-operating system. The functionality you describe involves massive interaction with the hardware, which is usually hidden by the operating system offering nice, high-level APIs.

A practical solution is probably to grab one of the many mini linux distributions and bundle their live images together with your application.

> > And will libraries such as stdio.h and stdlib.h even still be usable?

They won't, as their implementation is typically supplied by the operating system.